# Why does "-" before a number change the value, but "+" dosn't?

Tags: javascript

Why does "-" make a number, or a value that can be converted to a number with the "Number()" function, make it negative when a "+" just run the "Number()" function?

```
var num = 1
var numMinus = -num
```

This assigns "-1" to the variable "numMinus". But the other way around doesn't work.

```
var num = -1
var numPlus = +num
```

The "numPlus" variable still got the value "-1". Why?

Comment: Yes, but I don't really know what the "+" and "-" do behind the scenes. Could you explain?

Comment: Add a zero in the left and You will understand... it's just maths

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-num` can be read as `0 - num`, and `+num` can be read as `0 + num`. `0 + (-1)` is still -1. To clarify: `+num` does *not* mean "make num positive", that is called an absolute which you can get with `Math.abs`.